# Create a trigger that will show an error message when an account is updated to "Inactive" status, and has related open Activities and Asks

Tags: trigger

I am trying to write a trigger, that will show an error message, when an Account status is changed to "Inactive", and there are Asks that are not in ("Declined","Ask Not Made","Received")
Here is the code I wrote, but I think it is checking if there are any Asks in Opportunities set with this status, regardless of the Account. I need it to check only for the Account I am updating.

```
trigger inactivateAccountsRestrictions on Account (before update) {
if(!UserInfo.getUserName().contains('arcddcoe'))
{
     if(trigger.new[0].Status__c == 'Inactive')
    {   
            List<Opportunity> listAsks = [Select Id,Name,stageName from Opportunity where AccountId=:trigger.new[0].Id and stageName not in ('Declined','Ask Not Made','Received')];
            List<Task> listActivities =[Select Id,Status from Task where AccountId= :trigger.new[0].Id and Status<>'Completed'];

            if(listAsks.size()>0 && listActivities.size()>0)
            {
                if(listAsks.size() == 1 && listActivities.size() == 1)
                {
                     trigger.new[0].addError(' There is 1 open Ask and 1 open Activity on this Account. To inactivate this Account, you must first close the open Ask and Activity.');
                }
                else if(listAsks.size() == 1)
                {
                     trigger.new[0].addError(' There is 1 open Ask and '+listActivities.size()+' open Activities on this Account. To inactivate this Account, you must first close the open Ask and Activities.');
                }
}
```

Comment: this trigger is not bulkified. You are only referencing `Trigger.new[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a map of Opportunities and Tasks, like this:

```
List<Opportunity> listAsks = [Select Id,Name,stageName,AccountId from Opportunity where AccountId=:trigger.new[0].Id and stageName not in ('Declined','Ask Not Made','Received')];

List<Task> listActivities =[Select Id,Status,AccountId from Task where AccountId= :trigger.new[0].Id and Status<>'Completed'];


Map<Id,List<Opportunity>> oppMap = new Map<Id,List<Opportunity>>();
Map<Id,List<Task>> taskMap = new Map<Id,List<Task>>();

for(Opportunity opp : listAsks){
     List<Opportunity> oppList = new List<Opportunity>();

     if(oppMap.containsKey(opp.AccountId)){
          oppList = oppMap.get(opp.AccountId);
     }

     oppList.add(opp);
     oppMap.put(opp.AccountId, oppList);
}


/**The same with tasks**/
```

Then in your conditions use `oppMap.get(trigger.new[0].Id)` instead of `listAsks`.

Also I recommend you to iterate over trigger.new instead of referencing only the first account.

Comment: Thank you very much. Will give it a try. I do have other conditions as well I also account for, like if only Asks > 0 or Activities >0. I just did not include it, as I thought it would be adding unnecessary information.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be using AggregateResult for your trigger.

```
trigger inactiveAccountsRestriction on Account (before update) {
    Account[] inactiveAccounts = new Account[0];
    for(Account record: Trigger.new) {
        if(record.Status__c == 'Inactive') {
            inactiveAccounts.add(record);
        }
    }
    if(inactiveAccounts.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    Map<Id, AggregateResult> opps = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>(
        [SELECT AccountId Id, COUNT(Id) sum FROM Opportunity
         WHERE AccountId IN :inactiveAccounts AND
         StageName NOT IN 'Declined','Ask Not Made','Received')
         GROUP BY AccountId]
    );
    Map<Id, AggregateResult> tasks = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>(
        [SELECT AccountId Id, COUNT(Id) sum FROM Task
         WHERE AccountId IN :inactiveAccounts AND
         Status <> 'Completed'
         GROUP BY AccountId]
    );
    for(Account record: inactiveAccounts) {
        AggregateResult openOpps = opps.get(record.Id),
                        openTasks = tasks.get(record.Id);
        String[] message = new String[0];
        Integer oppCount = 0, taskCount = 0;
        if(openOpps != null) {
            oppCount = (Integer)openOpps.get('sum');
        }
        if(openTasks != null) {
            taskCount = (Integer)openTasks.get('sum');
        }
        if(oppCount == 0 && taskCount == 0) {
            continue; // Skip this record
        }
        // Display message based on values in oppCount and taskCount here
        // ...
    }
}
```